# Button styles in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just starting out with Bootstrap and I am stuck at the very initial stage. I am trying to modify the marketing-narrow.html (default example from docs/examples) to make the display button smaller.

I changed

```
 <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#">Sign up today</a>
```

to

```
 <a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="#">Sign up today</a>
```

and there was visually no change at all! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the inspect element tool in your browser, right click on the button and using this feature you can see what class the button is running off.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 Great tip. I just checked and it is in fact under the class btn-small. I even tried btn-mini. Neither works. :(

Comment: @Gowtham can you see the changes? http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/mwyvb

Comment: @YardenST Yes I can and that is exactly what I want too! What other changes did you make? I only changed the class of the button from the unzipped files. Did not touch any other file. Tried multiple browsers. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They override some attributes with this rule:

```
.jumbotron .btn {
     font-size: 21px;
     padding: 14px 24px;
}
```

the underline affect is that `btn-small` and `btn-large` are the same in .jumbotron context.

---

remove `jumbotron` class so the btn-small will work as expected:

```
<div>
        <h1>Super awesome marketing speak!</h1>
        <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="#">Sign up today</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I just figured this out! Thanks! Also, is it good practice to add !important at the end of my css to ensure that the properties I define override the default ones of bootstrap?

Comment: @Gowtham !important is never a good solution. you need to add your classes after bootstrap's classes and it will override them. see example http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/AKGlF

Answer (score 1):

Extra small button HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning  btn-xs" type="button">Extra small button</button>
<button class="btn btn-success  btn-xs" type="button">Extra small button</button>
```

[image]

http://twitterbootstrap.org/bootstrap-css-success-buttons/